# How to refresh data in a RecyclerView from a PagedListAdapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-pageradapter, android-paging, android-paging-library

Using the following lines of code, I can to display data from a backend server in a `RecyclerView` using `PagedListAdapter`.

```
movieViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MovieViewModel.class);
MovieAdapter adapter = new MovieAdapter(this);
movieViewModel.moviePagedList.observe(this, adapter::submitList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I created this method:

```
private void movieSearch(String searchText) {
    globalSearch = searchText;
    movieViewModel.replaceSubscription(this);
    movieViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MovieViewModel.class);
    MovieAdapter adapter = new MovieAdapter(this);
    movieViewModel.moviePagedList.observe(this, adapter::submitList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Which is called from inside `onQueryTextChange()` to display the results of the search but for some reasons the data in my `RecyclerView` is not refreshed.

This is also my `MovieViewModel` class:

```
public class MovieViewModel extends ViewModel {
    LiveData<PagedList<ApiResponse.Movie>> moviePagedList;

    public MovieViewModel() {
        MovieDataSourceFactory movieDataSourceFactory = new MovieDataSourceFactory(search);
        PagedList.Config config = new PagedList.Config.Builder().setEnablePlaceholders(false).setPageSize(20).build();
        moviePagedList = new LivePagedListBuilder<>(movieDataSourceFactory, config).build();
    }

    void replaceSubscription(LifecycleOwner lifecycleOwner) {
        moviePagedList.removeObservers(lifecycleOwner);
    }
}
```

I everytime I search something, I need to get freash data. How to solve this?

Comment: `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: @HB. Thanks but it doesn't work with `PagedListAdapter` :(.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49193372/5550161

Comment: I did it with 2 ArrayList, one for filtering and one to display all the items.

Comment: @HB. Let me try with 2 ArrayList.

Comment: @HB. I cannot get it done. You say to use 2 ArrayList in my MovieViewModel class, right?

Comment: Let me provide a answer then you can decide if you want to do it like I did.

Comment: @HB. Ok, I'm waiting for your answer. Thanks!

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be solved by calling

```
movieViewModel.moviePagedList.dataSource.invalidate()
```

in your activity/fragment.

Answer (score 1):

With this answer I will show you how I did filtering of items in my `Adapter`. Not answering your question directly, but rather giving you another solution.

First of, I have a `EditText` in my `ToolBar` called `m_app_bar_title_txt`, In my `Activity` I call the following:

```
//I'm using TextWatcher to see when text changes
m_app_bar_title_txt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        //If the text changes I call the following method
        //Passing the text to the metod
        filter(s.toString());
    }
});

private void filter(String s) {
    ArrayList<ScoresData> aData = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ScoresData mData : data){
        if (mData.textPlayerName.toLowerCase().contains(s.toLowerCase())){
            aData.add(mData);
        }
    }
    //this method is in my RecyclerView.Adapter class
    //I will provide this below
    mAdapter.filterList(aData);

}
```

`mAdapter.filterList(aData);` passes the filtered `ArrayList` to the following method inside my `RecyclerView.Adapter`:

```
public void filterList(ArrayList<ScoresData> filteredList){
    //Changing the original ArrayList -> data to filteredList
    //Then notifying that the list has changed
    data = filteredList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

If you where wondering what `ScoresData` looks like....

```
public class ScoresData {
    public String mImage;
    public String textPlayerName;
    public String textPos;
    public String textTotalScore;
    public String textPlayed;
    public String textRounds;
}
```

I hope this helps..

Comment: As you said, is not answering my question but it helped me solve it. I finally did it with your idea and the answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49192540/paging-library-filter-search/49193372#49193372).  Voted up! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`PagedListAdapter` is a subclass of `android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter` so a call to `notifyDataSetChanged()` will do.

Comment: I know that but it doesn't work. Do you have any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is written in the documentation of [DataSource](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/paging/DataSource#updating-paged-data)

> A PagedList / DataSource pair are a **snapshot** of the data set. **A new pair of PagedList / DataSource must be created** if an update occurs, such as a reorder, insert, delete, or content update occurs. A DataSource must detect that it cannot continue loading its snapshot (for instance, when Database query notices a table being invalidated), and call invalidate(). Then **a new PagedList / DataSource pair would be created** to load data from the new state of the Database query.

I think this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

call adapter.refresh()

```
swiperefresh.setOnRefreshListener {
  movieListAdapter.refresh()
  swiperefresh.isRefreshing = false
}
```

note movieListAdapter should extend PagingDataAdapter